# Updating object with belongs_to associations and nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got problems with making update action for one of my data objects. I've got:

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :post_address, :class_name => 'Address', :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_address
  # validations and stuff
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  # validations and stuff
end
```

And the problem is with the form and action:

```
= form_for @up, :url => '/profile/edit', :method => :post do |f|
  = f.error_messages 
  #...

    = f.fields_for :address,  @up.address do |a|
      #...

    = f.fields_for :post_address, @up.post_address do |a|
      #...

  .field.push
    = f.submit 'Save', :class=>'ok'
```

Action:

```
def edit_account
    @user = current_user

    if request.post?

      @up = @user.user_profile.update_attributes(params[:user_profile])

      if @up.save
        redirect_to '/profile/data', :notice => 'Zmiana danych przebiegła pomyślnie.'
      end   
    else
      @up = @user.user_profile
    end
end
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
Couldn't find Address with ID=3 for UserProfile with ID=2
```

And it occurs in the line:

```
@up = @user.user_profile.update_attributes(params[:user_profile])
```

I think that AR tries to create another `Address` when the form is submitted but I'm not certain.

Why do I get this error? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: can you show the controller bit for whatever action prepares the form for editing?

Comment: `@up = @user.user_profile` in the action I posted.

Comment: ah, sorry. I was thinking you were going the equivalent of new/create/edit/update RESTful controller actions.

Comment: Yeah... The thing is I'm not going that way in this case... And here I am with problems :)

Comment: Are you positive that you have your belongs_to setup correctly? Based on the class names, I would think you would define `has_one :address, :dependent => :destroy`

Comment: I had `UserProfile has_one :address` ant the same for :post_address but then the AR required to put reference fields to user_profile IN the addresses migration!

Comment: I looked at [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). I don't want `user_profile_id` AND `another_user_profile_id` in `addresses`! My design also allows to use one `Address` record for `address` and `post_address` field.

Answer (score 0):

So not sure how that works on new since @up.address is nil. Can you try something like:

```
=f.fields_for :address,  (@up.address.nil? ? Address.new() : @up.address) do |a|
  #...
= f.fields_for :post_address, (@up.post_address.nil? Address.new() : @up.post_address) do |a|
  #...
```

That might make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I just changed the type of association in `UserProfile`:

```
  has_one :address, 
          :class_name   => 'Address', 
          :foreign_key  => 'user_profile_id',
          :conditions   => {:is_post => false},
          :dependent    => :destroy

  has_one :post_address, 
          :class_name   => 'Address', 
          :foreign_key  => 'user_profile_id', 
          :conditions   => {:is_post => true},
          :dependent    => :destroy,
          :validate     => false
```

And slightly adjusted the controller. Thanks for help!